# .htaccess - hyphens in the URL - redirects fail - are previous directives interfering?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to get all my vlogs in a folder to run off a single PHP vlog page inside it. I'm using a simple redirect after I do all my strip/force housekeeping. But it 404's. What am I missing?

```
RewriteEngine on

# Follow symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Strip www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302]

# Force HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302]

# Strip php extension
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=302]

# Strip trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302]

#manage vlogs
RewriteRule ^/fol-der-name/(.+)$ /fol-der-name/vlog?url=$1
```

I tried these and they all fail

```
RewriteRule ^/fol-der-name/(.*)$ /fol-der-name/vlog?url=$1
RewriteRule ^/fol-der-name/(.+)$ /fol-der-name/vlog?url=%1
RewriteRule ^/fol-der-name/(.*)$ /fol-der-name/vlog?url=%1
```

Comment: I fail to spot the immediate conflict, but usually it makes sense to implement specific rules earlier, so further up in a list of rules so that they get processed first. Keep in mind that these configuration files are getting applied from top to bottom. Your last rule is very specific in that it has a fix prefixed path in it's pattern.

Comment: And another aspect: you should add `END` or `L` flags to your rules, there often (not always!) is little sense in proceeding with rewriting if a rule already got applied ...

Comment: Ok the first two rules would re-request, so no need for an L flag there, right? But the L halts all further processing of the file, so why use them when I want the file extension AND the trailing slash stripped?

Comment: There are situations where you need to combine a terminating flag for an external redirection. That is actually documented in the rewriting module.

Comment: For stripping a "file name extension" and a trailing slash: I fail to see a situation where that might _both_ be the case, but even if: keep in mind that the `L` flag only terminates _the current run_ of rewriting, not the entire rewriting process. So both rules _will_ get applied.

Comment: OK, if you need to dig deeper to find out what actually collides here I suggest you enable rewrite logging in your rewrite module. See the official documentation of the module on how to do that. Rewrite logging allows you to understand on a step by step base what is actually going on inside your rewriting engine.

Comment: When configured in .htaccess, the path RewriteRule matches against _never_ starts with a slash, that has already been stripped off at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was simple. Escape the hyphens on the LEFT SIDE in the last line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^fol\-der\-name/(.+)$ /fol-der-name/vlog.php?url=$1 [L,NC]
```

I finally fixed my own error, after a painful day and half, I kid you not, into the minutiae of .htaccess, learning things I didn't want to learn, and frankly don't feel any the wiser for knowing (eg did you know that Apache processes the RewriteCon conditions you write AFTER it processes the RewriteRule's you write?)

Anyway, I commend to all who have drowned in mod_rewrite or htaccess rewrite these 2 stunning pieces from my journey:

a) https://www.301-redirect.online/htaccess-rewrite-generator (this corrected the last line in my code in the question, and actually produced the fix - oh and it's the best .htaccess generator I've come across, and I looked at around 6)

b) https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/redirects/introduction-to-redirects (this explains a lot of how redirects should be coded, especially with queries - why use % v $ v slash - the final diagram on the page is worthy of a Nobel prize)